# Pass a special variable (~ tilde) to Java program

Tags: java, unix

I am trying to run a java program that takes a '~' tilde as a command line argument. Unfortunately when I run the program what I get is my home directory printed which I do not want. I am not sure how can I achieve the same ?

```
public class Test {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
                System.out.println(args[0]);
        }

}
```

Comment: I do not want to change the way I pass the argument. Its fixed

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put the tilde in single quotes:

```
java mypackage.MyClass '~'
```

I'm assuming you're using the bash shell, in which case `~` is automatically expanded to your home directory. Putting it in single quotes tells the shell not to expand it.

Comment: or prefix the tilde with a backslash (one less character :P)

Comment: I do not want to change the way I pass the argument. Its fixed

Comment: @WarriorPrince, `java` never sees the `~` because of [tilde expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Tilde-Expansion) so your only option (short of horrible hackery) is to pass command line arguments properly.