# Search and Replace in a variable string with Shell scripts

Tags: java, bash, shell, unix

I am in dilemma about how could I search and replace a particular character in a variable of a shell script.

e.g. I have a condition where I need to pass `'~'` to the java program but I should pass it as `'/~'` to avoid it being intercepted as $HOME. I have a shell variable e.g. `$1 = '.-~'`  and I am passing it directly to the Java program as an argument. So how could I modify this variable in such a way that it searches for `'~'` and if it finds then changes `$1 = '.-/~'` so as to avoid the error in Java program.

I tried `$(1//~//~)` but it gives me an error.

Also this gave me an error.

```
sed 's#~#/#g' <<< $x;
```

Comment: escaping the '~' with '/' to avoid it being intersepted as $HOME by bash.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass a special variable (~ tilde) to Java program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18808994/pass-a-special-variable-tilde-to-java-program)

Answer (score 0):

To replace a string in a shell variable, you can use var modifiers like this:

```
${YOURVAR/The string you want to search/The string you want to replace to}
```

By example:

```
${HOME/~/world} -> "hello ~" become "hello world"
```

Comment: it does not work for special chars : e.g. ${1/~/'/~'} does not work

Answer (score 0):

For both your attempts you have two options:

```
"${1//\~//~}"  ## ~ in pattern needs to be backslash quoted.
```

And

```
sed 's#~#/~#g' <<< "$x"  ## $x should be placed in double quotes to prevent other word splitting or expansions. And you probably forgot ~.
```

Other versions to replace with `\` instead:

```
"${1//\~/\\~}"
sed 's#~#\\~#g' <<< "$x"
```